# C++: std::initializer_list<T> as first argument in constructor causes compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, constructor, arguments, initializer-list

I was playing around with initializer lists and noticed some inconsistencies. Using an initializer_list as the first argument in a constructor causes a compilation error, but this doesn't happen for functions and member functions, or when other arguments precede the initializer_list.

This code illustrates what I mean:

```
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(initializer_list<int> list){}
    A(int a, initializer_list<int> list){}
    A(initializer_list<int> list, int b){}
    A(int a, initializer_list<int> list, int b){}
};

void B(initializer_list<int> list){}
void B(int a, initializer_list<int> list){}
void B(initializer_list<int> list, int b){}
void B(int a, initializer_list<int> list, int b){}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Ok
    A a = {1};
    A b(1, {2});
    A c(1, {2}, 3);
    B({1});
    B(1, {2});
    B({1}, 2);
    B(1, {2}, 3);

    // Error
    A d({1});
    A e({1}, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

And the build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Linal (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP), Configuration: Release2 x64 ------
1>  'Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP' is for testing purposes only.
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : '{'
1>main.cpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>main.cpp(31): error C2059: syntax error : '{'
1>main.cpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>main.cpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>main.cpp(31): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>main.cpp(31): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>main.cpp(33): error C2059: syntax error : 'return'
1>main.cpp(34): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>main.cpp(34): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is this correct behaviour? If so, why does this happen?

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 gives no errors. I'll bet GCC is right.

Comment: Have you considered installing the VC2013 preview, which probably has better conformance?

Comment: Fails to compile on VS2013 Preview as well, same errors

Comment: MSVC is not the best compiler to use with C++11. The upcoming C++14 is going to be released in a few months, and Microsoft doesn't provided the implementation of C++11 in an usable way yet.

Comment: 2015 is in a few month and it still fails...